# UnreachableBrowserException - Selenium script after PC updates. Everything worked fine before updates

Tags: java, selenium

**

- Environment -  Selenium 2.53.0 , Browser : Chrome

**

Issue : On triggering script , the browser does not launch and shows the below browser unreachabe exception. THE SAME SCRIPT WAS RUNNING FINE FOR MANY MONTHS AND NOTHING CHANGED IN APPLICATION. Started getting this wierd issue all of a sudden

**

- Resolutions Tried :

**

1. Localhost has only one entry 127.0.0.0
2. Upgraded Browser to specific version and started using the specific chrome driver
3. Same code base runs in another environment which is another RDP but it does not run from local machine

Starting Web Driver
Inside try with hubaddress: http://localhost:4675/wd/hub
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2020-12-10 08:58:42.884 Session could not be created.
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'SDERTWE-GDETYH', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'

Comment: What is your chrome version and chromedriver version?  - Chrome typically auto updates. You might have a mismatch.

Comment: We tried doing chrome browser update and driver update still same issue. Problem is the same browser and driver are working fine in other devserver but not in local machine after PC updates. Not sure what PC updates triggered this issue...